# Determine the monotonic intervals of the functions

Tags: calculus, functions

i need to determine the monotonic intervals of this function $y=2x^3-6x^2-18x-7$. I tried the below but i am not sure if i am doing it right.

My work: \begin{align} y=2x^3-6x^2-18x-7
&\Longleftrightarrow 6x^2-12x-18=0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow6(x^2-2x-3)=0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow(x-3) (x+1)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x-3=0 x+1=0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x=3, x=-1\\
\end{align}

so my function increases when
$x\in[3, +\infty[$ and decreases when $x\in[-1, 3]\cup ]-\infty, -1]$

Please i want to know how to solve this problem any help with explanation will be appreciated. thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly found the derivative

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=6x^2-12x-18=6(x^2-2x-3)=6(x-3)(x+1)$$

and where it is zero, but you have not quite got the intervals correct.

The derivatives is positive if and only if

$$(x-3)(x+1)>0$$

which is positive if and only if

$$(x>3 \text{ and } x>-1)\quad  \text{ or }\quad   (x<3 \text{ and } x<-1)$$

i.e. if and only if

$$(x>3)\quad  \text{ or }\quad   (x<-1)$$

So the function is (strictly) increasing on the interval $(-\infty, -1]$ and on the interval $[3,\infty)$.

The function is (strictly) decreasing on the interval $[-1,3]$.

Comment: OK thanks for your explanation on the interval